# Telerik RadGrid Problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

please see this picture first 
[image]

telerik sample is in this address
[Telerik RadGrid Sample](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/edit-form-types/defaultcs.aspx)

I Have 3 questions

1. How can I add **Add new record** button for Insert like sample

   How change **text** of it ?
2. How can I change text of **Edit** ? (telerik:GridEditCommandColumn)
3. How can I have **Refresh** button like sample ?

   How change **text** of it ?

Comment: Well, you are looking at the demo, copy the code and examine it to see which setting/tag results in what you see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How can I add Add new record button for Insert like sample

```
<MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="Top">
    <CommandItemSettings ShowAddNewRecordButton="true" />
     ..... 
     ..... 
</MasterTableView>
```

How change text of it ?

```
<MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="Top">
    <CommandItemSettings ShowAddNewRecordButton="true" AddNewRecordText="Your Text comes here" />
</MasterTableView>
```

How can I change text of Edit ?

```
<telerik:GridEditCommandColumn EditText="YourEditText"></telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
```

How can I have Refresh button like sample ?

```
<MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="Top">
    <CommandItemSettings ShowRefreshButton="true" />
</MasterTableView>
```

How change text of it ?

```
<MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="Top">
    <CommandItemSettings ShowRefreshButton="true" RefreshText="Youre Refrsh Text" />
</MasterTableView>
```

Let me know if any concern.